# Compatible MySQL_connect alternative in PHP 8.1

Tags: html, mysql, xampp, php-8.1

Have a xamp server running PHP Version 8.1.10. When trying to connect, it gives the following error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\elims\databaseConnect.php:7 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\elims\index.php(7): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\elims\databaseConnect.php on line 7

Commenting out the following lines with # logged me in the main window of the application but failed to connect with the sql batabes:

```
<?php 

$host='localhost';
$username='root';
$password='';
$database='elims';
**#** $connect=mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("databse connection failed...".mysql_error());;
**#** $db_select=mysql_select_db($database,$connect) or die("databse connection failed...".mysql_error());

 ?>
```

Do understand mysql_connect is nolonger applicatble in php versions higher than 7, then what works.

Comment: As you've already discovered, the `mysql_*` functions are long gone since version 7. Should use the `mysqli_*` (note the `i`) function equivalents instead, or better yet, maybe PDO. Note that if you do have the older `mysql_*` functions, there are _some_ differences in parameter position to the `mysqli` equivalents, but not too bad an effort to cover.